# Put value into application.yaml and use Runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

I have Spring boot application.
I want to put the some values as read timeout, debug mode in yaml file and then read them from java code.

**application.yaml**:

```
spring:
  jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
      show-sql: false


  datasource:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database_name
      username: database_username
      password: database_password


  http:
      multipart:
         maxFileSize: 15Mb
         maxRequestSize: 15Mb

server:
      port: 8585
      contextPath: /
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what is the question und what you've tried so far.

Comment: @RolandWeisleder i want put the variable in application.yaml and use into my java code same as `debug-mode: true`

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani are you talking about using different values of yaml variables in different profile. like different values for `dev` and different for `debug` or `prod`?

Comment: @FarooqKhan no i wan't put the variable such as debug-mode , read-timeout , socket-timout , api-token , ... into yaml and use this variable into code

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani have a look into: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `@Value` annotation provided by spring framework.

Here is the example:

```
api:
   values:
      socket-timout: 20
```

And in your java code you can get the value of `socket-timout` using the below code.

```
@Value("${api.values.socket-timeout}")
private Integer socketTimeout;
```

It will it will automatically be populated with value `20`. You can not do this for the static variables. To achieve this for the static variables, you can use the following code.

```
public static Integer mySocketTimeout;

@Value("${api.values.socket-timeout}")
public void setSocketTimeout(Integer socketTime){
   mySocketTimeout = socketTime;
}
```

By setting the the value of static variable via non-static setter method.

Comment: thank you.there is a way to read value an put into static field? i try this for static field and return null

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani I've updated the answer to cater your issue.